# How can clear or update cache in DirectAdmin?

Tags: php, apache, hosting, web-hosting, directadmin

In my host (directadmin) I was change 2-3 line of script and now I want to load that.. but always load old code...

For example I added `echo "hi";` to my first line of my script but when I run that again I see old result!

so I want to know how can I update that or clear cache or any other solution in `directadmin`

Note: I know if I create new file with new name I can see my new result but how to update old script? I don't want (I can't) to change location or name of that.

My DirectAdmin use from Apache.

Comment: When writing questions here, note that you do not need to use `<br>` tags - just use paragraphs instead. This makes future editing easier. Also, please respect standard case rules - your post is more likely to be answered if it looks like effort has gone into it.